# How can I detect start and end points of an edge with Aforge C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, edge-detection

I am currently detecting the corners of an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4ob.png) using SusanCornersDetector class from Aforge. What I wanted to get is the set of edges from an image by pairing the corners that I got from SusanCornersDetector.

Like:

```
SusanCornersDetector scd = new SusanCornersDetector();
Bitmap image = pictureBoxA.Image;
List<IntPoint> corners = scd.ProcessImage(image)
List<IntPoint,Intpoint> edges = new List<IntPoint,Intpoint>();
/**
code goes here
**/
```

I searched for other edge detection algorithm but what most of them does is they detect all the points from an image. I only wanted the starting and end points of an edge

Edit: [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPMkA.png) are the sample images that I will be using in my project

Comment: Is this the real image that you have to process ? Because it is very easy to handle by just following the black pixels and finding the changes in direction. Susan and edge detection would be overkill.

Comment: Most of the image that I will use is like that but I'm having trouble when the lines are too wide when I follow the black pixels

Comment: So this one is not representative enough.

Comment: I added some more images that I will be using. I just wanted to get all the edges even the intersections in the image

Comment: I can't see any "wide" line, what did you mean ?

Comment: You'd better turn the image to a graph by following the edges and analyzing the configurations around every pixel to detect corners and crossings.

Comment: Thickness I mean

Comment: Hem, I can't see any **thick** line, what did you mean ?

Comment: Basically it's just like those but some of the lines of the image that i will feed are 4-8 pixels thick

Comment: I had been asking you representative samples, but you didn't provide them. Use thinning.